# Вращение объекта по WorldAxis

Tags: webgl, three.js

Как повернуть объект относительно мировой оси, а не оси самого объекта по Ейлеру.
Трабл в том, если повернуть объект по одной оси, то это уже повлияет на его будущее вращение по другой оси, чего быть не должно.
Шаманство с rotation.order ничего не дало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение в одном из исходников на github.

Всего лишь нужно было обвернуть камеру в Object3D и вращать его по оси Z, а камеру - по оси X, таким образом камера по оси X будет вращаться не относительно Мира, а относительно Object3D.